# JNI folder has an error when make project[ndk-build] has an error

Tags: android, createprocess, ndk-build

I downloaded 'android netspoof' source code from [github android netspoof](https://github.com/w-shackleton/android-netspoof) , but when I compile the Project I am getting the following errors. How I can solve this problem?

```
Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'E:\dev\sdk\android-sdk-essential\ndk-bundle/ndk-build''
Error:net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'E:\dev\sdk\android-sdk-essential\ndk-bundle/ndk-build'
Error:java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "E:\dev\sdk\android-sdk-essential\ndk-bundle/ndk-build" (in directory "E:\dev\project\android\android-netspoof-2.4.0\androidnetspoof"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
Error:java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```